# Error al usar el .join() python

Tags: python

Hola buenas noches a todos, estoy haciendo una consulta a una API, que me debería de devolver las primeras 5 noticias de cryptos, les muestro el código:

```
def reporte_noticias():
    palabra = ""
    consulta = json.loads(requests.get(f"https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=ES{clave}").text)
    for i in range(5):
        palabra.join(consulta['Data'][i]['title'])
    return palabra 

print(reporte_noticias())
```

El problema pasa que, a la hora de printear el valor, sale en blanco.
Alguien sabe porque podría ser?
Ayer había hecho el código, con el Join, y funcionaba, el tema es que se me borró y hoy no logro replicarlo.
Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Depende de el formato que tenga `consulta`, sería más fácil ayudar si compartes eso.

Comment: Y qué es eso del valor `{clave}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
def reporte_titulos(cantidad_titulos: int = 5) -> list:
    URL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=ES"
    response = requests.get(URL)
    consulta = json.loads(response.text)
    return [ consulta.get("Data")[num].get("title") for num in range(cantidad_titulos) ]

print(reporte_titulos())
```

Y al ejecutarlo te dará una lista con los 5 primeros valores:

```
['¿Cuáles son los cambios más recientes en el impuesto sobre los ingresos brutos en algunas provincias de Argentina?', 'Bitcoin no presenciará una recuperación hasta que esto suceda', 'Altcoin Roundup: 3 formas en las que la tecnología blockchain podría alcanzar una mayor adopción en 2022', 'Sega habría registrado la marca Sega NFT en Japón', 'Bitfinex aconseja a los usuarios residenciados en Ontario que cierren sus cuentas antes del 1 de marzo']
```

Y ya a estos valores les puedes aplicar las funciones que quieras

```
def reporte_titulos(cantidad_titulos: int = 5) -> list:
    URL = "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/v2/news/?lang=ES"
    response = requests.get(URL)
    consulta = json.loads(response.text)
    return [ consulta.get("Data")[num].get("title") for num in range(cantidad_titulos) ]

primeros_n_titulos = reporte_titulos()

titulos_str = ":".join(primeros_n_titulos) 

print(titulos_str)
```

Dándote como resultado:

```
¿Cuáles son los cambios más recientes en el impuesto sobre los ingresos brutos en algunas provincias de Argentina?:Bitcoin no presenciará una recuperación hasta que esto suceda:Altcoin Roundup: 3 formas en las que la tecnología blockchain podría alcanzar una mayor adopción en 2022:Sega habría registrado la marca Sega NFT en Japón:Bitfinex aconseja a los usuarios residenciados en Ontario que cierren sus cuentas antes del 1 de marzo
```

Donde utilizamos `join`, de esta manera:

```
<separador>.join(iterable)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la detallada explicación. Me sirvió mucho eso de ' -> list'. No sabía que existía.

Comment: Pfff. Te va a servir muchísimo! Se le llama *type hinting*. Y en realidad solo ayuda a los desarrolladores a saber qué tipo de variables necesitan o regresarán. IDE's como PyCharm los utilizan mucho y son de una ayuda asombrosa. No son "necesarios", pero si son muy recomendados. Hacen el código más "auto descriptivo".

Answer (score 0):

El error está en que estás iterando por fuera del `str.join()`, algo así

```py
Iterador i->
    str.join(valor[i])
```

Mientras que la lógica correcta sería:

```py
str.join(Iterador i)
```

**Join** toma el iterador del argumento de la función para unirlos en un `string` o cadena de texto. [Ver ejemplos](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/join)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación!